# Nginx user change causes blank screen on Chrome and 200 error

Tags: php, nginx, ubuntu-16.04, fastcgi, nginx-config

My main `nginx.conf` file had user set to `nginx` like so:

```
user                 nginx;
```

I am looking to switch the user to the default `www-data` user but running into issues. If I change the user in the conf file and reload nginx, Chrome displays a blank page and console shows the following error:

```
net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR 200
```

As soon as I switch the user back to nginx and reload, it works fine.

What am I missing when switching the user? Here is the config file.

```
user                 nginx;
pid                  /var/run/nginx.pid;
worker_processes     auto;
worker_rlimit_nofile 65535;

# Load module section
load_module "modules/ngx_http_brotli_filter_module.so";
load_module "modules/ngx_http_brotli_static_module.so";

events {
    multi_accept       on;
    worker_connections 65535;
}

http {

    upstream php {
        server unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        server unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock backup;
    }

    charset              utf-8;
    sendfile             on;
    tcp_nopush           on;
    tcp_nodelay          on;
    server_tokens        off;
    log_not_found        off;
    types_hash_max_size  2048;
    client_max_body_size 16M;

    # MIME
    include              mime.types;
    default_type         application/octet-stream;

    # Logging
    access_log           /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log            /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;

    # Limits
    limit_req_log_level  warn;
    limit_req_zone       $binary_remote_addr zone=login:10m rate=10r/m;

    # SSL
    ssl_session_timeout  1d;
    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_tickets  off;

    # Mozilla Modern configuration
    ssl_protocols        TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;

    # OCSP Stapling
    ssl_stapling         on;
    ssl_stapling_verify  on;
    resolver             1.1.1.1 1.0.0.1 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 208.67.222.222 208.67.220.220 valid=60s;
    resolver_timeout     2s;

    # Cache Settings
    fastcgi_cache_key    "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri";

    # Load configs
    include              /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include              /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone else comes across this, I've figured it out.

In my case, the reason for the blank screen was because of the caching setup. As soon as I deleted everything inside `/var/cache/nginx` I was able to switch the Nginx user as desired.